# BindException: Address already in use: Cannot bind

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, multi-user

I have a JSF webpage and form. On submit i validate the model number that was entered in. When I run the bit of code in JUnit that throws the exception all my tests pass just fine. When I enter in a model number and am the only one logged in this form it works just fine. I'm thinking this is a race condition of sorts...

the code that fails is this

```
public static int getCountOfSameModelsInItemInventory(String[] models) {
    int count = 0;
    if (initialize()) {
        try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(AOurl, userName, password)) {
            count = TryWithConnection(models, conn);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SqlInformationHolder.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

the line number indicates that it fails here `try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(AOurl, userName, password)) {`

I have a C# background so my first instinct is to use a lock around my Connection, but I don't think java has that. My research is saying that the error is thrown if the port is already in use.I'm not sure if this is enough information or not, but I will edit my post if need be.

So I guess in the end I have 2 questions.. the obvious one: "How do I fix this", and two is there a design pattern/ best practice that would help avoid this?

On average I have about 5 people using the webpage,  <s>and this is the only method that makes a call to this specific server</s> . The other methods use a different SQL server.

**EDIT**

so I have 1 other method that makes a call to this server. I'm looking at it to see if all the resources are cleared.

**EDIT**

```
Oct 08, 2014 9:17:09 AM dli_qc_v2.SqlInformationHolder getCountOfSameModelsInItemInventory
SEVERE: null
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The connection to the host OURSERVER, named instance THEINSTNACE failed. Error: "java.net.BindException: Address already in use: Cannot bind". Verify the server and instance names and check that no firewall is blocking UDP traffic to port 1434.  For SQL Server 2005 or later, verify that the SQL Server Browser Service is running on the host.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:190)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.getInstancePort(SQLServerConnection.java:3589)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.primaryPermissionCheck(SQLServerConnection.java:1225)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:972)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:827)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1012)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at dli_qc_v2.SqlInformationHolder.getCountOfSameModelsInItemInventory(SqlInformationHolder.java:110)
    at dli_qc_v2.DLIModelValidator.validate(DLIModelValidator.java:56)
    at dli_qc_v2.NcpFormBean.verifyingModelValue(NcpFormBean.java:327)
    at dli_qc_v2.NcpFormBean.fillForm(NcpFormBean.java:230)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor447.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:278)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:273)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:83)
    at javax.faces.component._MethodExpressionToMethodBinding.invoke(_MethodExpressionToMethodBinding.java:88)
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:100)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:120)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot._broadcastAll(UIViewRoot.java:937)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:271)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot._process(UIViewRoot.java:1249)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:675)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationExecutor.execute(InvokeApplicationExecutor.java:34)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:171)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2442)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2431)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: your test code pass under an exception because you are not throwing it, it is been just logged. Add the piece of code 'throw ex' and you will see your tests fail.

Comment: my test code asserts that the count returned is > 0. not that there is an exception or not

Comment: Sorry, I missed that... could you post the full stacktrace error? the getConnection method signature only throws a SQLException, so it is weird that it is returning a BindException

Comment: @fmodos Added Stacktrace.

Comment: The junit run in the same machine as the webserver? Maybe there is some blocking connection configuration activated in the sql server... try to do the steps: Open the tool 'Sql Server Configuration Manager', 'Client Protocols' and check if it has TCP/IP enabled, if nto enable it